# How to map row results from one table as headers for another table in a query

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have two tables, one is a holding tank for data, and another is to store user defined column headers for the columns in the holding tank.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HoldingTank]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [B] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [C] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [D] [nvarchar](max) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_HoldingTank] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HoldingTank] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[HoldingTank] ([Id], [A], [B], [C], [D]) 
VALUES (1, N'VALUE1', N'VALUE2', N'VALUE3', N'VALUE4')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[HoldingTank] OFF 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ColumnHeaders]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnLetter] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [ColumnHeading] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsUsed] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_ColumnHeaders] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ColumnHeaders] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[ColumnHeaders] ([Id], [ColumnLetter], [ColumnHeading], [IsUsed]) 
VALUES (1, N'A', N'Custom1', 1),
       (2, N'B', N'Custom2', 1),
       (3, N'C', N'Custom3', 1),
       (4, N'D', N'Custom4', 1)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[ColumnHeaders] OFF
```

The goal is build a query that return the `ColumnHeading` values from the `ColumnHeaders` table in the place of the normal column headings in the `HoldingTank`, so instead of

```
Id      A       B       C       D
------  ------  ------  ------  ------
1       VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4
```

it would return:

```
Id      Custom1         Custom2         Custom3         Custom4
------  --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
1       VALUE1          VALUE2          VALUE3          VALUE4
```

Pretty sure this is either a PIVOT or a combination of PIVOT and UNPIVOT.

Unfortunately, every variation and example I have tried always seems to assume a static (and known ahead of time) value in the headers table.  Unless I'm missing something incredibly basic.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times.